# Base href ignored in IE9

Tags: html, .htaccess, internet-explorer-9

I use a rewrite methode:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)$ search.php?q=$1
```

for prevent affecting on url of css and images , i used `<base href="http://localhost/project/" />` at the page header.

in FF and Chrome everything works fine, but in IE9 it still adds "page" (rewrited url) to all page urls and makes: `http://localhost/project/page`

what is problem?

Comment: Use the opportunity to quit using `base`, for example using the `-f` switch: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: i now added `rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.css$
` before rewrite methode and still not work.

Comment: Don't use relative urls, but root-relative urls. So `<link href="css/main.css" ...` becomes `<link href="/project/css/main.css" ...`